# Why does the Fatal error appear: Cannot redeclare exc_post () when if ($ _SESSION ['filter1'] == '')?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am writing a tag filtering plugin for wordpress but for some reason I get an error

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare exc_post () (previously declared C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ wor \ wp-content \ plugins \ GOG11 \ GOG11.php: 64) in C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ wor \ wp-content \ plugins \ GOG11 \ GOG11.php on line 141
```

On line

```
 if ($ _SESSION ['filter2'] == '') {
```

And the most curious thing is that on the exact same line only

```
 if ($ _SESSION ['filter1'] == '') {
```

There are no errors
And it only occurs when

```
 ['filter2'] == ''
```

for all other values, everything works fine
If, instead of skipping, I indicate 1, then the error appears already on filter4 jumping filter3

Here is the entire plugin code.

```
      session_start();
      if ($_POST['filter1']){   
    $_SESSION['filter1'] = $_POST['filter1'];
    }

      if ($_POST['filter2']){   
    $_SESSION['filter2'] = $_POST['filter2'];
    }

     add_shortcode ('wp-r_dop_filter','A2'); 
    function A2(){




        $R1='

<form method="POST" >
<p>Option filter</p>

<p>Filter 1</p>
level 1:  <input type="radio" name="filter1" value="1"' . ($_SESSION["filter1"] == 1 ? 'checked' : '') . '/> 
level 2:  <input type="radio" name="filter1" value="2"' . ($_SESSION["filter1"] == 2 ? 'checked' : '') . '/> 

<p>Filter 2</p>
level 1:  <input type="radio" name="filter2" value="1"' .  ($_SESSION["filter2"] == 1 ? 'checked' : '') .  '/> 
level 2:  <input type="radio" name="filter2" value="2"' .  ($_SESSION["filter2"] == 2 ? 'checked' : '') .  '/> 



<p><input type="submit" value="User"></p>
</form>
       ';

       return  $R1;
    }











if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == ''){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter1_query_lv0 ) {
    if ($filter1_query_lv0->is_category || ($filter1_query_lv0->is_home || ($filter1_query_lv0->is_feed) || ($filter1_query_lv0->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter1_way_lv0_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter1_way_lv0_2 = file_get_contents( $filter1_way_lv0_1 . 'filter1/level_1.txt');   
$filter1_way_lv0_3 = explode (",", $filter1_way_lv0_2);  



        $filter1_query_lv0->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter1_way_lv0_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter1_query_lv0;
}
}
else if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == 1){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter1_query_lv1) {
    if ($filter1_query_lv1->is_category || ($filter1_query_lv1->is_home || ($filter1_query_lv1->is_feed) || ($filter1_query_lv1->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter1_way_lv1_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter1_way_lv1_2 = file_get_contents( $filter1_way_lv1_1 . 'filter1/level_1.txt');   
$filter1_way_lv1_3 = explode (",", $filter1_way_lv1_2);  



        $filter1_query_lv1->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter1_way_lv1_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter1_query_lv1;
}

}
else if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == 2){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter1_query_lv2) {
    if ($filter1_query_lv2->is_category || ($filter1_query_lv2->is_home || ($filter1_query_lv2->is_feed) || ($filter1_query_lv2->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter1_way_lv2_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter1_way_lv2_2 = file_get_contents( $filter1_way_lv2_1 . 'filter1/level_2.txt');   
$filter1_way_lv2_3 = explode (",", $filter1_way_lv2_2);  



        $filter1_query_lv2->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter1_way_lv2_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter1_query_lv2;
}

}   



if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == 1){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter2_query_lv0) {
    if ($filter2_query_lv0->is_category || ($filter2_query_lv0->is_home || ($filter2_query_lv0->is_feed) || ($filter2_query_lv0->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter2_way_lv0_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter2_way_lv0_2 = file_get_contents( $filter2_way_lv0_1 . 'filter2/level_1.txt');   
$filter2_way_lv0_3 = explode (",", $filter2_way_lv0_2);  



        $filter2_query_lv0->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter2_way_lv0_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter2_query_lv0;
}
}
else if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == 2){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter2_query_lv1) {
    if ($filter2_query_lv1->is_category || ($filter2_query_lv1->is_home || ($filter2_query_lv1->is_feed) || ($filter2_query_lv1->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter2_way_lv1_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter2_way_lv1_2 = file_get_contents( $filter2_way_lv1_1 . 'filter2/level_1.txt');   
$filter2_way_lv1_3 = explode (",", $filter2_way_lv1_2);  



        $filter2_query_lv1->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter2_way_lv1_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter2_query_lv1;
}

}
else if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == ''){

add_filter('pre_get_posts','exc_post'); 
function exc_post($filter2_query_lv2) {
    if ($filter2_query_lv2->is_category || ($filter2_query_lv2->is_home || ($filter2_query_lv2->is_feed) || ($filter2_query_lv2->is_tag)))  
    {
$filter2_way_lv2_1 = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );  
$filter2_way_lv2_2 = file_get_contents( $filter2_way_lv2_1 . 'filter2/level_2.txt');   
$filter2_way_lv2_3 = explode (",", $filter2_way_lv2_2);  



        $filter2_query_lv2->set('tax_query', array(  
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $filter2_way_lv2_3,  
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter2_query_lv2;
}

}
```

the code has been simplified.

Comment: because it was "previously declared"  ....

Comment: you have `function exc_post(...` in the file above *six* times, you cant reuse the same function name.

Comment: In particular if the flags overlap. Try to clean up the spaghetti code, and abstract the function if it only differs ever so slightly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's your simplified version, I don't want to know how the original version looked like. Nevertheless - the whole problem is, that you defined the function `exc_post` two times - one time for each filter, but each time exactly the same way. An easy solution would be to rename the functions for the first filter to `exc_post1` and the other to `exc_post2`.

That would work, but still isn't a good solution, as the main part of your logic is duplicated 6 times. So each time you change your function, you have to change 6 places instead of one, which is a very bad practice.

It would be better to define the filter function one generic time and reuse them, as only the filename changes and everything else is the same.

```
function exc_post($filter, $file) {
    if ($filter->is_category || ($filter->is_home || ($filter->is_feed) || ($filter->is_tag)))
    {
        $dir = plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ );
        $content = file_get_contents( $dir . $file);
        $terms = explode (",", $content);

        $filter->set('tax_query', array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' =>  $terms,
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        ));
    }
    return $filter;
}

if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == '') {
    $file = 'filter1/level_1.txt';
} else if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == 1) {
    $file = 'filter1/level_1.txt';
} else if ($_SESSION['filter1'] == 2) {
    $file = 'filter1/level_2.txt';
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', function($filter) use ($file) {
    return exc_post($filter, $file);
}, 0);


if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == 1){
    $file = 'filter2/level_1.txt';
} else if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == 2){
    $file = 'filter2/level_1.txt';
} else if ($_SESSION['filter2'] == ''){
    $file = 'filter2/level_2.txt';
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', function($filter) use ($file) {
    return exc_post($filter, $file);
}, 0);
```

Comment: Yes. That would be a great solution. Only it gives me an error
 Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 75

Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 77

Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 75

Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\wor\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 77

Comment: What's your wordpress version?

Comment: I have a version 4.9.8

Comment: maybe this is because: 3 parameter ($priority) should not be a function but a number

Comment: I think I was able to change it slightly, but it only applies to either filter1 or filter2 is there a way to apply filters at the same time `add_filter('pre_get_posts',function($filter) use ($file) { 
    return My_filter_post($filter, $file);
});`